# how to predict the arpu for a monthly cohort dynamically?

Tags: machine-learning, python, time-series, regression, training

The main idea of this project, is to predict the **ARPU** (Average Revenue Per User) 11 month after subscription of a cohort with a monthly subscription, using minimum number of delays (a delay is a month of data of a cohort, i.e.: `delay 0` --> first month of data for cohort A, `delay 1` --> second month after subscription ...), now the idea is to predict the ARPU using maximum 3 months of data, in a way everytime a cohort has another month of data we predict the ARPU of 12th month :

- cohort A subscribed in 01/2021 --> Predict ARPU of 12/2021 using data of 01/2021
- in 02/2021 --> Predict ARPU of 12/2021 using data of 01/2021 and 02/2021
- in 03/2021 --> Predict ARPU of 12/2021 using data of 01/2021 and 02/2021 and 03/2021

(more data = better accuracy, but for business requirements we cant wait more than 3 month of data for a cohort to get good predictions)
I'm wondering how to make this possible, considering that data is stored in Snowflake.

Comment: ARPU = Average revenue per user

Comment: yes exactly ARPU is average revenue per user

Comment: For the connection to Snowflake connection you can check: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/python-connector/python-connector-example